# extjs dynamic number of columns

Tags: layout, extjs, extjs4

I'm looking for way of having dynamic number of field columns in Extjs form.

Basically form should look like this(2 columns):
[image]

But when user shrinks the browser width, it should change to this (1 column):
[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I guess that this is not possible. After form will be rendered - table with fields will be rendered, you cannot change columns list at that time. Son only one way I see - is to regenerate form with the correct columns count at specific event.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible to do this. You just need to use a little bit of CSS to get things working. I applied my CSS directly in my form config, but you could just as easily put it in its own CSS file.

```
    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'auto',
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            style: {
                float: 'left',
                width: 200
            }
        },
        items: [
            { fieldLabel: 'Field 1' },
            { fieldLabel: 'Field 2' },
            { fieldLabel: 'Field 3' },
            { fieldLabel: 'Field 4' },
            { fieldLabel: 'Field 5' },
            { fieldLabel: 'Field 6' }
        ]
    });
```

As you resize the browser to where two columns won't fit, you should see the two columns automatically wrap into one column.

I've made an example for you to view here: http://jsfiddle.net/Asuza/n7Zsj/

When you open it up you should see two columns of fields. Change the CSS body width to 300px and re-run the fiddle and the number of columns should now be one. This should be equivalent to you resizing the browser manually.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to play with different layouts. First think I would try is to set form layout to anchor and specify fixed width for all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Please use column layout.

```
{
    xtype:'container'
    layout:'fit',
    items:{
        xtype:'form',
        title:'test',
        layout:'column',
        items:[...]
   }
}
```

FOr text fields don't set width